# How can I extract strings with a particular pattern from a list of strings in MAKEFILE?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, makefile

I have a 'dirs' and 'files' defined as follows in a MAKEFILE

```
dirs := Documents Desktop
files := $(foreach dir,$(dirs),$(wildcard $(dir)/*))
```

I want to extract entries from 'dirs' those have 'Doc' in the begining to other list and check if the list is empty. The entries may be paths also as follows.

```
final_list := some operation on files
```

I tried many ways of doing it using wildcard search but was unable to do so. Can you help me out?

Comment: Do you want to have the entries that have `Doc` at the beginning of the path, such as `Documents/foo.txt`, or those whose filename begins with `Doc`, such as `Desktop/Docfoo.txt`?

Comment: @Wintermute: Yes I want to have entries that have Doc at the beginning of the path, such as Documents/foo.txt. Thanks for pointing the case out.

Answer (score 3):

Use the filter function:

```
final_list := $(filter Doc%, $(files))
```

[`filter`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html) filters a list for all entries that match any of one or more given patterns. In this case, it gives you all entries in `$(files)` that match the pattern `Doc%`.

Comment: Thanks this works. I want to raise a warning if the list is not empty I tried using                                                                                                     $(ifneq $((strip $(final_list)),),,\
$(warning This is abcd))                                                                                                               But this does not seem to work.

Comment: You can use `ifneq ($(strip $(final_list)),)\n  $(warning This is abcd)\nendif` (replace the `\n` with newlines). I don't think the `strip` call is necessary, actually, so `ifneq ($(final_list),)\n  $(warning This is abcd)\nendif` should also work. Note that this block has to appear after `final_list` is set.